# It's possible show an input window requesting information to the user in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I want to do with Javascript or jQuery the same I do with `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` in Java.

Show an input window to the user enter some information.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`prompt(text, value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.prompt) for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something more stylish or involved than merely a prompt (which Quentin answered with), that's a very involved question that's likely too complex to answer here.

Try doing a google search for "jquery modal form".  You'll find lots of tutorials.

[Like this one.](http://jorenrapini.com/blog/css/jquery-validation-contact-form-with-modal-slide-in-transition)